# I have a 4 x 4 grid how can i programmatically work out if a random number is the far right square

Tags: actionscript-3, math, random

so say i have a grid:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3

4 - 5 - 6 - 7

8 - 9 - 10 - 11

12 - 13 - 14 - 15
```

(but will be more rows...)

how can i find out programmatically if a random number (within the range of the numbers) is equal to the far right number: 3,7,11,15...?

thanks

Comment: How is this grid stored? Is it always arranged like that, or could the numbers be all jumbled up? How many more rows are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( ( random_number + 1 ) % number_of_columns == 0 ) {
  // on right
}
```